# I am very much confused with computed property in vue as it is applying the data to computed property but not rendering?

Tags: javascript, laravel-5, vuejs2, vue-component

```
        computed: {
        filteredQuestions: function () {
            return this.allquestions.filter((question) => {
                return question.question.match(this.search)
            })
        }
    },
```

I have above computed property and I am getting data in created method in following way:

```
        created() {
        axios.get('/teacher/quiz/questions')
            .then((response) => {
                console.log(response.data);
                this.allquestions = response.data;

            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
    },
```

I have declared allquestions and search in my data method.
After instatiation the data is not displaying.
[image]

but at the same time it is showing in vue inspection tools.
due to which I am confused about it. Whats actually happening behind the scenes?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`axios.get` is asynchronous operation.
so, when the program runs for the first time, `this.allquestions` is actually still `undefined` and your computed method fails.

I would declare upfront `allquestions` as an empty array on the `data` property.

See the code:

```
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      allquestions: []
    }
  },
  computed: {
    filteredQuestions: function() {
      return this.allquestions.filter(question => {
        return question.question.match(this.search)
      })
    }
  },
  created() {
    axios
      .get('/teacher/quiz/questions')
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response.data)
        this.allquestions = response.data
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error)
      })
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: thank you very much. I understood the error as it was my silly mistake. I already had declared allquestions but as an object like allquestions: {} in data and after changing ut to array the problem is solved.